# Alamofire request with Parameters

Tags: ios, http, networking, alamofire

I have this url : https://eee.com/geo?lat=10.2&lng=10.2

And i want to pass 2 parameters instead of 10.2. How should Alamofire request looks ?

Comment: Base URL: " https://eee.com/geo", parameters: `["lat":10.2, "lng":10.5]`?

Comment: Its should be get or post ? :) I am new in networking tbh. In response I will get json

Answer (score 2):

if **Request method** is **Get**,May be

```
    Alamofire.request("https://eee.com/geo?lat=10.2&lng=10.2").responseData { (dataResponse) in

        if let data = dataResponse.data {
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
        }
    }
```

if **Request method** is **Post**,May be

```
    Alamofire.request("https://eee.com/geo", method: .post, parameters: [ "lat" :10.2,"lng":10.2 ] ).responseData { (dataResponse) in

        if let data = dataResponse.data {
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
        }
    }
```